# Magento Rest API Redirects to Customer Account After Login

Tags: magento, rest, oauth, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

**Hi!**

I've been working with the **Magento REST API** and **OAuth 1.0** for an iOS application that fetches products only for customers (not guests).

Along the token-request process i've encountered with the following issue:

*Whenever i try to obtain a token without prior login i get redirected to a login form. After submission it redirects me to the user account panel. 
However when i'm logged in and try to request the token i get redirected to the url for the required application authorisation.*

I believe that in both scenarios i **should be redirected** to the application **authorisation url**. Am i correct? In that case, where should i start for debugging the process?

Below is the **PHP code** I'm using for testing purposes, as it is easier for me to debug with PHP rather than Objective-C.

```
<?php
/**
 * Example of products list retrieve using Customer account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
 */
$callbackUrl = "http://*******/oauth_customer.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://*******/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://*******/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://*******/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://*******/api/rest';
$consumerKey = '*******';
$consumerSecret = '*******';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```

**I would appreciate any help**
Federico

Comment: Same problem here.. With 1.8.1.0.. Any luck in finding out the solution?

Comment: And same problem here, did you guys find anything? My Version is 1.9.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the code provided here ?
https://iqbalmp.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/magento-update-a-product-using-rest-api/